# How to handle listeners if both views and models(objects) should listen to model(object)?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, architecture

`Passenger`s and `Taxi`s run independently in different threads. After great help of  Edwin Buck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967754/what-is-wrong-in-my-mvc-implementation/10969242#10969242) I used MVC for Taxi management. In my situation both view(`JTaxiPanel`) and models(`Passenger`) listen to `Taxi`. When `Taxi` fires event(for example when passenger is added or taxi start driving...) all listeners are notified. The problem is that `Passenger` will be notified even if other passengers are added to taxi. I want passenger to listen, but I don't think that `Passenger` should be notified when **other** passengers are added or in some other situations.

How to handle this kind of problem?

Should taxi have 2 list of listeners or there is some other way to do it?

```
class Station extends Thread
{
    LinkedList<Taxi> taxisInQueue;
    LinkedList<Passenger> passengersInQueue;
    void matchPassengerToTaxi()
    {
         Taxi taxi = taxisInQueue.removeFirst();
         Passenger passenger = passengersInQueue.removeFirst();
         // passenger listen to taxi
         taxi.addListener(passenger);
         taxi.addPassenger(passenger);       
    }
}
class Passenger extends Thread implements TaxiListener
{
    @Override
    public void taxiChanged(TaxiEvent event)
    {

    }
}
class Taxi extends Thread
{
    Vector<Passenger> passengers;
    public void addPassenger(Passenger passenger) 
    {
        passengers.add(passenger);              
        // notify listeneres
        fireEvent(new PassengerAddedEvent(this, passenger));
    }    
}
class JTaxiPanel extends JPanel implements TaxiListener
{
    public JTaxi(Taxi model)
    {
        this.model = model
        // view listens to Taxi
        model.addTaxiListener(this); 
    }
    @Override
    public void taxiChanged(TaxiEvent event)
    {        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generalize what you are saying: event/listener is a broadcast communication pattern.  If you build a system where many listeners are ignoring most broadcasts, you are asking for performance problems and adding complexity in the listeners.

To fix this, choose different communication channels implemented as different event and listener types for different kinds of communication.  In this case, rather than a single event type that means "something happened to the taxi", find different classes of events that happen to a taxi and that have smaller listener sets.

A rule of thumb is that the most frequently occurring events should have the smallest number of listeners ignoring them.

Another rule of thumb is to make these different types of events mutually exclusive.  You don't want a case where the same entity is notified twice of the same event.

Another approach frequently used in GUI systems is an event mask.  When a listener is installed, a mask of desired event types is included. This lets the sender (in this case the Taxi) avoid sending to a listener that isn't interested.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you basically suggest to use at least 2 sets of listeners, like `viewListeners` and `modelListeners`? But this couples `view` to `model`, does it?

Comment: No not view and model listeners. Rather different message types sent by model components to different listener sets.  You didn't say enough about your problem for good examples.  For the case you gave, you could have a "SinglePassengerNotify" event/listener list where when a passenger enters or leaves, only that passenger is notified. And you could also have a "AllPassengerInTaxiNotify" event/listener list for notifying passengers that the taxi has broken down, etc.

Comment: what do you need to know more? I thought I provided all necessary information. Please tell and I'll provide

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your passenger listener if the passenger which has been added is the same as `this`. Comparing ids or some other equality criteria. If they are not the same, they don't do anything...